# Jquery Slide out box

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I have a problem with a script in my page.

Here my case

http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page%20copy.html

If you click on *productos* link a div box falls down from the top. My idea is that if i click again in the *productos* link the div goes back. I am very close to achieve it but in my case as you can see my div goes back and then falls down again.

This is the script where i am probably doing something wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#productos_link').click(function(){
                $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    $('#productos').animate({'top':'110px'},500);
                });
            });
            $('#productos_link').click(function(){
                $('#productos').animate({'top':'-400px'},500,function(){
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });

        });

</script>
```

Where is the mistake? , how i need to change the script to get my slide box goes back and not falling down again when i click for the second time on productos link?

Here you find the tutorial i have used

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/03/css-and-jquery-tutorial-overlay-with-slide-out-box/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/show/)

demo is slow but try to in your code

```
$(function () {
    $('#productos_link').toggle(function () {
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $('#productos').animate({ 'top': '110px' }, 500);
        });
    }, function () {
            $('#productos').animate({ 'top': '-400px' }, 500, function () {
                $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
            });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a "toggle" or "state" variable, so that you can check to see if its already visible or not.

Something like this might work (I haven't tested this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#productos_link').each(function(){
        this.toggled = false;

        $(this).click(function(){
            switch(this.toggled){
                case true:
                    this.toggled = false;
                    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                        $('#productos').animate({'top':'110px'},500);
                    });
                break;
                default:
                    this.toggled = true;
                    $('#productos').animate({'top':'-400px'},500,function(){
                        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                    });
                break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's because in the tutorial, they're using a seperate element to close the box. You're using the same one, so it will be triggering both events when you click on it (hence it closing and reopening again).

I've just realised the mistake I made in your code, I shall fix it now

Comment: yes i just realised that in the tutorial they use separate element..so glad if you can fix my code..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#productos_link').click(function(){
                $('#overlay').not(':visible') ? function() {
                    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function(){
                        $('#productos').animate({'top':'110px'}, 500);
                    });
                } : function() {
                    $('#productos').animate({'top':'-400px'}, 500, function(){
                        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                    });
                }

            });
        });
</script>
```